# Widgets in WP 4.3 disappearing - How to fix?

Tags: widgets

I definded my widgets as seen in the following code. Since update 4.3 Wordpress did some changes i can not fix. Any ideas what i need to change in order to see the widget in the frontend again? I can edit and see it in the backend widget menu, but not in the frontend.

```
class Z_Suche extends WP_Widget {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct( false, $name = 'Z Suchfeld', array( 'description' => 'Suchformular im Z-Style.' ) );

}

function widget( $args, $instance )
{
    ?>
        <div class="widget" id="sidebarsearch">
            <h3>Suchen</h3>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
            return $instance;
}
function form( $instance ) {}
}
register_widget('Z_Suche');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in WordPress 4.3. The authors have made the necessary revisions to core and it will be fixed in WordPress 4.3.1.

In the meantime, you can patch your version of WordPress. The details are here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33442